# Readonly element delete with backspace

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to delete an element like span when the user press the backspace key?

Example:

I have a div contenteditable="true". 
Inside the main div, I insert multiple words and also:

```
<span readonly style="color:green">text</span>
```

The goal to reach :
When the user is writing, he can choose word in a list. The user can't delete it char by char. So it's the role of "readonly" to delete all the word when the backspace is pressed.

Readonly works great with Chrome, bug in IE and Firefox use only the "delete" touch before to remove all the word.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZpgeg)

```
var editableDiv = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]');
editableDiv.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 8) {
      var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      if(editableDiv === range.commonAncestorContainer && range.endOffset === 0) {
        // remove the last readonly span
        var container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];
        var lastReadOnlyChild = document.querySelector('span[readonly]');
        container.removeChild(lastReadOnlyChild);
      }
    }
});
```

Basically, when ever user presses backspace remove the last readonly from DOM if cursor position of editable div is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution, tested in chrome:
https://jsfiddle.net/8y09ngry/1/

```
// you need to find your editable div, best way is to use id
document.getElementById('holder').onkeydown = function(e) {
    // listen only backspaces, but you can add "Delete" as well 
    if (e.keyCode == 8) { 
        // getting target element, this may looks little different in IE
        var target = window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode;
        // checking 'readonly' attribute and deleting element
        if (target.getAttribute('readonly') != null) {
            target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```js
 $('#mydiv').bind('backspace ', function(event) {
    //console.log(event.keyCode);
    switch(event.8){
       //....your actions for the keys .....
    }
 });
 
 $(function() {
   $('#mydiv').focus();
});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" tabindex="1" >asdf asdf
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not ask for votes/accepts here, Ankit. If the material is good then people will give you good votes naturally.